# Laying Text on Top of a background Image in an HTML table

Tags: html

I am a relative newbee to HTML.  Please be gentle!

I am trying to lay some text on top of a background image in am HTML email and am getting lost in the finer syntax.  The background image is not showing up.  I believe it is in fact getting pulled, but simply not being rendered  (I could be very wrong)

```
<table width="100%">
   <tr>
  <td style="margin:0; padding:0; margin-top:1px; background-image:url ('http://www.insurehomehealth.com/MM/greenbar.png')";>My Text</td>
  </tr>
</table> <!--end table-->
```

Thanks for teaching me a in advance!

Comment: Stackoverflow is loosing my table close!

Comment: You closed the quotation before the `;` after the background-image thing

Comment: Oh thanks!  That is in fact an error, but it does not resolve the issue.  When I use:  <td style="margin:0; padding:0; margin-top:1px; background-image:url ('http://www.insurehomehealth.com/MM/greenbar.png');">My Text</td> I still have no backgoud image

Comment: now you are missing the `http://www.` in the background url and the space between `:url` and `('`

Comment: Thanks Travis.  I did in fact have the http://www. but it got eaten by stack overflow.

Comment: Thank Amir.  You have helped me solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added a space between `url` and `(`

So replace:

```
background-image:url ('http://www.insurehomehealth.com/MM/greenbar.png');
```

by

```
background-image:url('http://www.insurehomehealth.com/MM/greenbar.png');
```